# Is there a way to check each function in an R package against only the imports in its own roxygen2 comment block?

Tags: r, namespaces, roxygen2

I am making an R package, and I'm using roxygen2 to auto-generate my NAMESPACE file, which means I am declaring my imports in the roxygen2 comments above each function in my package, something like this:

```
#' @importFrom somePackage someFunc someOtherFunc
f1 <- function() {
    someFunc()
    someOtherFunc()
}

#' @importFrom somePackage aThirdFunc
f2 <- function() {
    someFunc()
    aThirdFunc()
}
```

However, despite being placed next to the individual function declarations, the  `@importFrom` declarations are global to the entire package namespace. That means that the import of `someFunc` above `f1` in my example also works for `f2`, even though I forgot to include `someFunc` in the imports for `f2`. This means that it is easy to let these declarations get out of sync with their associated functions, which con result in unexpected behavior later down the line. For example, if I chose to remove `f1` from my package in the future or reimplemented it so that it no longer used `somePackage`, and I removed the corresponding import statement, `f2` would suddenly be broken.

So, to avoid this, is there any way I can check each function against only its own import declarations to ensure that they are always in sync and not implicitly relying on imports declared for other functions? Or should I just abandon this entirely and go back to manually maintaining my NAMESPACE file?

Comment: Do you have a package file (name-package.R)?  One thing you can do is put the imports in there.

Comment: The idea is to have all the imports for each function be documented with the function itself. Moving them all to a separate file defeats that.

Comment: Well that's one way to approach it but it's not the only way. The choice is not just between what you are doing and manually managing your NAMESPACE. Alternatively don't forget anything in your imports.

Comment: I know it's not the only way to approach it. But my question is whether roxygen2 provides any tools to facilitate keeping per-function imports in sync with the functions they're annotating, independent of other imports in the package.

Comment: How could it know where that function came from given that it's okay to have the same function names in each package? I'm pretty sure you just have to be totally accurate if you are going to do it that way.

Comment: It doesn't have to know where the function came from. It just has to tell me something like "no import for `someFunc` in `f2`" (in the above example).

Comment: But many functions do not need to be imported. That's the whole danger you've identified  of not having a full list, that it will use a same named function from a different package.

Comment: @Elin That's not correct. All functions must be imported into a package namespace.